# Access denied for user in php

Tags: php, mysqli

psl-config.php

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Das sind die Login-Angaben fur die Datenbank
     */  
    define("HOST", "localhost");     // Der Host mit dem du dich verbinden willst.
    define("USER", "xxx_sec_user");    // Der Datenbank-Benutzername. 
    define("PASSWORD", "xxx");    // Das Datenbank-Passwort. 
    define("DATABASE", "xxx_secure_login");    // Der Datenbankname.

    define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
    define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

    define("SECURE", FALSE);    // NUR FUR DIE ENTWICKLUNG!!!!
```

That's the connection script to my MySQL databse. But now it tells me

> [28-Dec-2017 14:29:22 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning: 
>   mysqli::__construct(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'xxx_sec_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/beta_login/includes/db_connect.php on line 3

What am I doing wrong ?

db_connect.php

```
  <?php
        include_once 'psl-config.php';   // Da functions.php nicht included ist
        $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

Comment: I'm assuming your password or username is incorrect. If not, then are you trying to connect to a remote server?

Comment: the password is right, I tried localhost but also the remote ip

Comment: So is it a remote server? If so, the server may require you to approve your remote IP address to be able to access the database.

Comment: it works now, just changed define to variables